# In Pokemon Go, if your Pokemon storage is full, would it be a good idea to transfer away Pokemons just because of Movesets?

Tags: pokemon-go

For example, for Dewgong and Cloyster, they have Icy Wind, but they seem to be quite useless, because they don't do much damage (in terms of DPS). And Dewgong also has Aqua Jet, but it is a water move, which is not useful if you want ice move. Cloyster has Hydro Pump, which is actually a powerful move, but it is not an ice move if what you want is ice move.

So I plan to transfer away all the Dewgongs with Icy Wind or Aqua Jet, and and Cloysters with Icy Wind or Hydro Pump. (and keep only the ones with Blizzard).

Is this in general a good idea? Does anything make this not a good idea?

Comment: This question might be covered by others analyzing move sets.  The question as written is asking for opinions, which are hard to answer and supposedly not suited for Stack Exchange Q&A.  If this question is still on your mind, consider revising it to be less opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime issue for playing the game strategically.  And we're not going to know for sure if we've made great choices until  we see the changes that Niantic can make in server programming come, or not come, in the future.  The fixed cool down wait times programmed now work very well with some gymn defenders moves and very poorly with others.  Pokémon with some movesets work better defending gymns than attacking and vice versa.  Type differences are critically important.  If Dragonite has Dragon Breath and Dragon Claw it will be strong against a different set of Pokémon types than it will when it has Steel Wing and Hyper Beam. Place the latter in a gym and it will be relatively difficult to plan the takeover of a gymn as the wrong attackers will be selected by the attacking trainer.

In the case of Cloyster and Dewgong, they are both slightly disadvantaged by lower Max CP already, so their usefulness is limited to a few narrow attacks, such as against the Steel Wing Dragon where Clefairy is useless.  In that case Cloyster's Frost Breath and Ice Shard attacks are relatively equal, and Blizzard is a must.  Only very obscure situations will make Aqua Jet useful in an Ice Pokémon and Icy Wind is underpowered. So, indeed, certain moves make a Pokémon useless in your hand and you might as well get rid of them.

But I keep around a few powerful types with seemingly weak moves for some situations.  For instance, the Fire Fang move is generally more powerful than Bite in an Arcanine, but Bite is pretty strong against Vaporeon by comparison with Fire Fang. In a gymn, the attacking trainer can only tell by the absence of "not very effective" messages that bite is employed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your level and with regards to how seriously you intend to play. If you are a low-level player, like only just having chosen your team, CP is what you want to focus on. It's when you hit the higher levels, like level 15 or so, when moves also come into play, and may make a lower CP Pokémon better than a higher CP one.

Of course, CP doesn't matter if you're not interested in Gyms, but then you're missing out on a fun side of the game.

Comment: doesn't low level play also consider move? If a Dewgong has CP 800 and Blizzard and another Dewgong has CP 1000 and Icy Wind, I think probably it is wise to transfer away the CP 1000 Dewgong

Comment: If you have Pokémon with 800+ CP, you're not in low level play.

Comment: but what is low? Even if I have a Dewgong with CP 400 and Icy Wind, versus one with CP 300 with Blizzard, I might choose one with Blizzard, unless if the level is so low that there probably is no chance to even use the charge move

Comment: I don't know the exact specifics. But if the CPs are close, moves are a lot more important.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally found that original move sets do not necessisarrily affect the evolved movesets and have on multiple occasions had pokemon evolve only to recieve worse moves than it had before...so it would seem they are truely random.

if you are not happy with the moveset of a completely evolved pokemon your only real option is to transfer the unwanted ones and hope the next one you try to evolve will get the moves you wanted....a sad product of the devs not including traditional trainer procedure of choosing to keep moves or take new ones....

I would suggest that in the case of more rare pokemon as seals can be in many areas that you may want to keep at least one to set as your partner pokemon so you can get the free candy to level them up quicker than hunting out enough candy...

if the pokemon is one of your highest cp pokemon though I would hold on to it anyways for a while,as if you do fight gyms and win, each day you can collect 10coins for every gym you actively hold possession of once a day(23hrs) which you can use to increase the number of pokemon you can have....and honestly if you are a big fan of their product it may be reasonable to spend a few bucks real to get the coins and thank the devs for the app you are enjoying....